# Resize datagridview table to the control

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview that looks like this :
[image]

and I want to resize my table inside so that it fits it exactly. Do you have any idea on how to do it?

I tried this:

```
            this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

But I don't know how to do it for the rows

Answer (score 0):

All .Net controls have a `Dock` property. See [Control.Dock Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

And, all .Net controls also have an `Anchor` property. See [Control.Anchor Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Docking can be set in the designer via:

[image]

The `Dock` property will cause the target control to take up all of the space in the selected section (Top, Bottom, Left, Right, or Fill) and it can be set to work with other controls that are also Docked.

Anchors can be set in the designer via:

[image]

The `Anchor` property will cause the target control to lock its location on the form along side the selected edges (Top, Bottom, Left, or Right). As any of the edges of the Form move, the corresponding edge of the control will move to maintain the same distance. Clearing all selected values will cause the control to essentially, float and not resize.